# How to Spread Plot's Date Axis According To Years When Plotting With Seaborn?

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, seaborn, linear-regression

I'm trying to train a Linear Regression Model with Python via using Google Stock Prices that can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/medharawat/google-stock-price
And trying to predict future stocks by given features. After that I'm planning to plot it with the values in current dataset.

First, I read dataframes with date values with date parser and concatted these 2 dataframes into one in order to split it myself:

```
parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
df_test=pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/google-stock-price/Google_Stock_Price_Test.csv",parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)
df_train=pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/google-stock-price/Google_Stock_Price_Train.csv",parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)
df=pd.concat([df_train,df_test])
```

Then I changed the type of Close column as "float64" and plotted the Date-Close relation via using seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.relplot(x='Date', y='Close', data=df,kind="line")
```

The output is:

[image]

I've managed the necessary column translations until this part of the code. In this part I split the data frame, create and trained model, and predicted values.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=df[["Open","High","Low","pc"]]
y=df["Close"]     
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
model.score(X_test,y_test)
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
```

What I want to achieve after this part is I want to set these predictions' dates for future dates in order to combine them into my data frame and plot. I managed to create 2 data frames for real and predicted data and concat and melt them into new dataframe in order to plot it.

```
dates=(df[-320:]["Date"]).values
df_plot=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","Close"])
df_plot["Date"]=dates
df_plot["Close"]=y_test.values.transpose()

df_predd=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Predicted","Date"])
df_predd["Predicted"]=y_pred.transpose()
df_predd["Date"]=dates
df_predd["Date"]=df_predd["Date"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=8) #I want to plot it as future predictions

concatenated = pd.concat([df_predd.assign(dataset='df_predd'), df_plot.assign(dataset='df_plot')],axis=0)
melted_df=pd.melt(concatenated,id_vars=["Date"],value_vars=["Predicted","Close"])

sns.relplot(x='Date', y='value', data=melted_df,hue="variable",style='variable',kind="line",height=10)
```

Here's the undesired output:

[image]

I want an output something like that:
[image]

What Am I Missing? I checked the Date Column's type. It's datetime. I can't spread the x-axis as the first plot shown above.
Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your example, consider these two toy dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

df_actual = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "date"  : pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", periods=8, freq="MS"),
    "value" : np.random.randint(10, 30, 8),
})

df_forecast = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "date"  : pd.date_range(start="2020-08-01", periods=4, freq="MS"),
    "value" : np.random.randint(10, 30, 4)
})
```

If you want to plot the actual and forecast values together on a shared x axis, the easiest way I can think of is to differentiate them by adding a `type` column and feeding it to the `hue` parameter of seaborn's lineplot.

Remember to "connect" the two lines by making the first value of the forecast dataframe the same as the last value of the actual dataframe:

```
#first forecast value == last actual value
df_forecast.iloc[0, :] = df_actual.iloc[-1, :]

df_forecast["type"] = "forecast"
df_actual["type"] = "actual"

df = pd.concat([df_actual, df_forecast])
```

Finally, you create your plot like so:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(x="date", y="value", hue="type", data=df)
```

[image]