# Change the line style of the same line in a plot Seaborn Facetgrid using a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, facet-grid

I am trying to create a plot like

[image: this one]

where the line style changes after a predetermined x-value. I am using Seaborn Facetgrid with a pandas dataframe input in tidy format.

My input dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> print(plot_df)
dataset  x  y  style
dogs     1  2  solid
dogs     2  3  solid
dogs     3  1  solid
dogs     5  6  dashed
cats ....
```

I have tried to use `hue_kws` as below but this has no effect.

```
style_list = plot_df[style].tolist()
g = sns.FacetGrid(plot_df, hue="dataset", hue_kws={"ls":style_list})
g.map(plt.plot, "x", "y").add_legend()
```

How can I achieve this successfully?

EDIT: Thank you for the suggestion of the [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378414/how-to-spread-plots-date-axis-according-to-years-when-plotting-with-seaborn) I had not found that. However it does not answer my question as that question relies on using the `hue` parameter to change the linestyle. Not only would this result in a different colour for the dashed section of the line (which I don't want) it would also clash with my use of the hue section to differentiate by dataset.

Note: I am also using the row and column functionality of Facetgrid but I have excluded these for simplicity.

Comment: You'll need a separate line for the dashed segment. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378414/how-to-spread-plots-date-axis-according-to-years-when-plotting-with-seaborn/63397672#63397672) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you only have one point labeled 'dashed', when you need at least 2 points to draw a line.
I would suggest the following:

```
cutoff_x = 3
d = '''
dataset  x  y
dogs     1  2
dogs     2  3
dogs     3  1
dogs     5  6'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\\s+', header=0)
```

> ```
> dataset    x   y
> 0  dogs    1   2
> 1  dogs    2   3
> 2  dogs    3   1
> 3  dogs    5   6
> ```

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1['x']>=cutoff_x].assign(style='dashed')
```

> ```
> dataset    x   y   style
> 2  dogs    3   1   dashed
> 3  dogs    5   6   dashed
> ```

```
df = df1.drop(df1.loc[df1['x']>cutoff_x].index).assign(style='solid').append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

> ```
> dataset    x   y   style
> 0  dogs    1   2   solid
> 1  dogs    2   3   solid
> 2  dogs    3   1   solid
> 3  dogs    3   1   dashed
> 4  dogs    5   6   dashed
> ```

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="dataset")
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "x", "y", style="style")
```

[image]